# Rails, STI and nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, routes, sti

I have the models `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3` and `foo4`, which are subclasses of `foo`. And I have models like `bar` and `baz`.

Models `bar` and `baz` contain objects of type `foo` and of all its children. Also, each type has an action called `next`.

Now I must setup routes like

```
resources :bar do
  resources :foo do
    member do
      get :next
    end
  end
  resources :foo1 do
    member do
      get :next
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

I could use `concern`, to avoid setting the same to `bar` and `baz`, but I would still have to add `get :next` to every subtype of `foo`.

Is there some rails magic to do this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your question is about reducing duplication in the `routes` file, you can simply loop through arrays of keys:

```
[:bar, :baz].each do |parent|
  resources :parent do
    [:foo, :foo1, :foo2, :foo3, :foo4].each do |children|
      resources :children do
        member do
          get :next
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, that looks quite gross, so you may want to have another look at the design of your app and determine whether this is really necessary. Also, keep in mind that Rails expects a plural key as an argument to `resources`, so you may need to figure out what the plural of a key like `:foo1` is (`:foo1s`, perhaps?).